# Alt, control and function keys are suddenly being detected as if they were shift keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on a Medion Akoya laptop running Windows 10, and since a few days, the control, alt and fn keys are not working properly. If I open the on-screen keyboard, pressing the alt, control or fn key registers as pressing the shift-key. I have checked the keyboard/language settings and can find nothing strange, nor can I find any other problems or improper settings. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?